# Grabbing the image, post title, and post date from tumblr's API

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

I found Nathan Scott's javascript snippet for embedding a tumblr feed on a static webpage extremely useful. But I am also finding it a bit too simple in terms of the info I want to get. With my limited knowledge I cannot seem to figure out how to also call the Post's Title and the Date so that I can style it with CSS. I would also ideally like to state that I only get the first photo from the regular post and truncate after X amount of characters but I've had no luck.

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated!

here is the original code courtesy of Nathan Scott!

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://collinsstreetmedia.tumblr.com/api/read/json"> 
 </script>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
  $("#announcement").html(
    tumblr_api_read["posts"][0]["regular-body"].substring(0,400)
  );
  $("#announcement_url").attr(
      {
        href: (tumblr_api_read["posts"][0]["url"])
      }
    );
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading and testing out different approaches using the official documentation? It seems straightforward... http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

The endpoint you want for fetching a post is this:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[TUMBLR WEBSITE HERE]/posts/text?api_key=[YOUR API KEY]
```

For example:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/citriccomics.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=[YOUR API KEY]
```

Then using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) you can call that request:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/citriccomics.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=[YOUR API KEY]", function(data) {
   alert(data); // Do something with 'Data', your JSON response.
});
```

To actually parse JSON you can use something simple like:

```
var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(responseData.response.posts);
```